# I have Added a doc to SOLR index but stopword does not apply

Tags: solr, stop-words

I have configured a SOLR installation 4.10.3 with schema.xml with the followin lines :

```xml
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have indexed the text field, and inserted some stopword in the stopword.txt file. But the configuration gives an error when I restart solr.
Please how to make it working the stopwords ?
Thank you

Comment: Where is your schema..? Can you post the schema.xml been used and error logs?

Comment: Please share the error you're getting (and the schema portion, too)

Comment: The `schema.xml` block looks okay to me now, but the answer depends _a lot_ on what error message you're getting.